# different approximation methods (dataGrouping) for each Series in one Highstocks-Chart?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to set individual approximation methods for multiple line-series in one Highstock-Chart?

Let's say i want to have 'average' dataGrouping on a temperature-line-plot und a custom method on some other line-plots in the same highstock-chart.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set dataGrouping for each series. Example:

```
series: [{ 
    dataGrouping: {
        approximation: 'average'
    },
    data: [ ... ]
}, { 
    dataGrouping: {
        approximation: 'sum'
    },
    data: [ ... ]
}]
```

Comment: Found a nice example about the datagrouping [over here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/rangeselector/datagrouping/), but summing the y-values goes wrong. Is it possible to add a callable for calculating the new y-value?

Comment: In my opinion it works properly, see: http://jsfiddle.net/36s685st/ - just remember, that dataGrouping works on a range of points and calculate one point according to them. Previously calculated points don't matter. As for callback, use `dataGrouping.approximation = function () { ... };` instaed of `string`.